# Error when empty data is passed to mv-expand in kusto

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I'm using kusto to query logging data, some of which have a list of dynamic properties (irrelevant details omitted):

```
  {
    "OperationId": "b07f6e4aa0ed180a8131e90a374665cb",
    "TimeGenerated [UTC]": "12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM",
    ...
    "Properties": {
      "Message": "Updating label",
      "AspNetCoreEnvironment": "Debug",
      "Category": "General",
      "DeveloperMode": "true",
      "DynamicProperties": 
       "[
            {"Key":"Id","Value":"{GUID}"},
            {"Key":"Source","Value":1},
            {"Key":"ExcludeToUser","Value":true}
        ]"
    },
    ...
  }
```

I was having a bit of an issue reading the `ExcludeToUser` field since it's an JSON object inside of a list, but this kusto query solved it for me:

```
let ExcludeToUser = toscalar(
Events
| project-keep Properties, TimeGenerated
| where TimeGenerated between ( datetime(2022-12-05, 10:15) .. datetime(2022-12-05, 10:25) )
| project p = Properties | evaluate bag_unpack(p) | mv-expand todynamic(DynamicProperties)| evaluate bag_unpack(DynamicProperties)
| project-keep Key, Value
| where Key == 'ExcludeToUser' and Value == false
| summarize result = count() >= 1);
```

The key was using mv-expand and bag_unpack.

My problem is that if I change my search query to something where nothing is returned or `DynamicProperties` is null, I get the following error:

> 'mvexpand' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'DynamicProperties'

Seems to me like mv-expand fails when no data is there for it to expand. Is there a way to check if no data is returned?

The following is sample data exported as csv, example of good data:

```
OperationId,Properties,"TimeGenerated [UTC]"
b07f6e4aa0ed180a8131e90a374665cb,"{""Message"":""Updating label"",""AspNetCoreEnvironment"":""Debug"",""Category"":""General"",""DeveloperMode"":""true"",""DynamicProperties"":[{""Key"":""Id"",""Value"":""guid""},{""Key"":""Source"",""Value"":1},{""Key"":""ExcludeToUser"",""Value"":true}]}","12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM"
```

The output from quyering this data would be: True (there exists a row where the DynamicProperty ExcludeToUser exists **and** it is true. The exact same data but with ExcludeToUser set to false should return False.

Example of bad data:

```
OperationId,Properties,"TimeGenerated [UTC]"
b07f6e4aa0ed180a8131e90a374665cb,"{""Message"":""Updating label"",""AspNetCoreEnvironment"":""Debug"",""Category"":""General"",""DeveloperMode"":""true""}","12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM"
```

Quyering this data **should** return false, but throws the error above.

Comment: Please provide a sample data as a datatable + required results in csv format. Make sure that the sample data contains a "good" example and a "bad" example. Also please explain what you are trying to count and why do you need all this complexity if it all ends with a count.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! I'll edit and add some data. I'm trying to count the occurences of the dynamic property ExcludeToUser, basically just return true if the ExcludeToUser key exists and is true. If this is true, we don't show the given log to our end users (we're using this in our application). The complexity comes from the object being in a list, and my guess is there's probably a better way to do this that I don't know about.

Comment: The technical problem you encountered can be easily solved, but bag_unpack is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) operator will do the trick.

```
let Events = datatable(OperationId:string, Properties:dynamic, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    "Op1" ,dynamic({"Message":"Updating label","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Debug","Category":"General","DeveloperMode":"true","DynamicProperties":[{"Key":"Id","Value":"guid"},{"Key":"Source","Value":1},{"Key":"ExcludeToUser","Value":true}]}) ,"12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM"
   ,"Op2" ,dynamic({"Message":"Updating label","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Debug","Category":"General","DeveloperMode":"true"}) ,"12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM"
   ,"Op3" ,dynamic({"Message":"Updating label","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Debug","Category":"General","DeveloperMode":"true","DynamicProperties":[{"Key":"Id","Value":"guid"},{"Key":"Source","Value":1},{"Key":"ExcludeToUser","Value":false}]}) ,"12/5/2022, 10:19:14.271 AM"
];
Events
| mv-apply item = Properties.DynamicProperties on (where item.Key == "ExcludeToUser" and item.Value == false)
```

| OperationId | Properties | TimeGenerated | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Op3 | {"Message":"Updating label","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Debug","Category":"General","DeveloperMode":"true","DynamicProperties":[{"Key":"Id","Value":"guid"},{"Key":"Source","Value":1},{"Key":"ExcludeToUser","Value":false}]} | 2022-12-05T10:19:14.271Z | {"Key":"ExcludeToUser","Value":false} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA92TwUoDMRCG7/sUQ04trG13VcSVHkpbpEitYOtFekibcQ1kkyXJrpbad3fSVRb00pMHk9v8/8x8zDAKPUxr1N7BEAT39DcKO4sSLffS6JnInLdS5zE8WENRL9FlYqd5IbcxLGWBt6iDGUVG%20egp0o2eI6DHFmXCIP5yd/Zsjs7xHFnGViWZqSwovkHFYjZy5T36sbE41bW0RhcERcYJbqqc9DHVzo3dUahpGJImWKMKVHMjQlVvKwzhpmELzLLnPbvDkDwTZHjiqgr%20vJKCHeJv7dFUdoutnrTS9H2rKoFLs3JoW0doeFgfuhCzJO1f9tNBmsaQDLLkOksueulVAqM5C8OIaRjp3w/jVLTz/72nF67cKYta30TNNUQfUNRnvCzVDqTHgq6jxez9AgejofP2ihaP7h7BwHAIP3CAa9HoR6zgOIJ1PwFrFxTChgMAAA==)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the defaultifempty() operator like in the below kusto:

```
defaultifempty()
```

or perhaps you could use

```
| project DynamicProperties = iff(isnull(DynamicProperties) or isempty(DynamicProperties), [{"Key": "ExcludeToUser", "Value": false}], DynamicProperties)
```

Both should work for your use case if I am understanding it correctly, though the iff statement is probably quite intensive so like I am frequently told it should probably be configured differently prior to ingestion

Comment: defaultifempty?

Comment: I can't find any reference to ```defaultifempty```. When using ```iff(isnull(DynamicProperties))``` I get the same error as before: ```'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'DynamicProperties'``` It can't check null on a value that does not exist...

Comment: Sorry this really should've been a comment as I don't have the rep to comment. I thought defaultifempty carried over to KQL too. After my own research it looks like column_ifexists() is the best resort to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `bag_unpack` is needed and you could just provide an empty array in case `DynamicProperties` is `null`. The following should work:

```
let ExcludeToUser = toscalar(
Events
| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2022-12-05 10:15) .. datetime(2022-12-05 10:25))
| project dp = coalesce(Properties.DynamicProperties, dynamic([]))
| mv-expand dp
| project Key = tostring(dp.Key), Value = tostring(dp.Value)
| where Key == 'ExcludeToUser' and Value == false
| summarize result = count() >= 1);
```